# Return data from setTimeout in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, cron

I have a function that gets data from amazon api. I want to call it after few seconds to avoid too many requests error from amazon. For that, i decided to go with setTimeout(). The problem is that, i need to return the data from the function that makes an api call into amazon, i am using promises for that. It looks like that the function that makes an api call to amazon is being called but then i get an error saying, `fn.apply() is not a function`

Below is the utility function that i have created.

```
export const fetchPriceAfterDelay = (fn, delay) => {
  let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(async (...args) => {
      let importedData;
      try {
        importedData = await fn(...args);
        resolve(importedData);
      } catch (err) {
        reject(err);
      }
    }, delay);
  });
  return promise;
};
```

The below function is responsible for making api call to amazon

```
export const getProductPrice = async (ASIN, marketPlace) => {
  const requestParameters = {
    ItemIds: [ASIN],
    ItemIdType: 'ASIN',
    Resources: ['Offers.Listings.Price'],
  };
  commonParameters.Marketplace = marketPlace;
  try {
    const productPrice = await amazonPaapi.GetItems(
      commonParameters,
      requestParameters
    );
    return productPrice;
  } catch (err) {
    throw new Api500Error(err);
  }
};
```

and below is how i am calling the utility function.

```
amazonProductPriceChange = await fetchPriceAfterDelay(
            getProductPrice(
              item.productData.ASIN,
              item.productData.marketPlace
            ),
            2000
          );
```

and i am getting the below error.

```
TypeError: fn.apply is not a function
┃     at _callee$ (/Users/nabeel/Documents/ShopifyApps/amazon_importer/server/cron/cronUtils.js:6:32)
┃     at tryCatch (/Users/nabeel/Documents/ShopifyApps/amazon_importer/node_modules/@babel/polyfill/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:63:40)
┃     at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (/Users/nabeel/Documents/ShopifyApps/amazon_importer/node_modules/@babel/polyfill/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:293:22)
┃     at Generator.next (/Users/nabeel/Documents/ShopifyApps/amazon_importer/node_modules/@babel/polyfill/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:118:21)
┃     at asyncGeneratorStep (/Users/nabeel/Documents/ShopifyApps/amazon_importer/server/cron/cronUtils.js:8:103)
┃     at _next (/Users/nabeel/Documents/ShopifyApps/amazon_importer/server/cron/cronUtils.js:10:194)
┃     at /Users/nabeel/Documents/ShopifyApps/amazon_importer/server/cron/cronUtils.js:10:364
┃     at new Promise (<anonymous>)
┃     at Timeout._onTimeout (/Users/nabeel/Documents/ShopifyApps/amazon_importer/server/cron/cronUtils.js:10:97)
┃     at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:554:17)
┃     at processTimers (internal/timers.js:497:7)
```

Comment: `getProductPrice(item.productData.ASIN, item.productData.marketPlace)` isn’t a function.

Comment: `...args` in this `setTimeout` call will always be empty. Note that [`setTimeout`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/setTimeout) accepts arguments after `delay` that become the parameters of the callback function.

Answer (score 1):

`getProductPrice` does *not* return a function. You are passing the return value of `getProductPrice` into `fetchPriceAfterDelay` as the argument for `fn`.

Instead, you could pass in the function without `()` and the arguments for the function as a second parameter. So you can call FN inside `fetchPriceAfterDelay`.

Comment: `{ item.productData.ASIN, item.productData.marketPlace }` is syntactically incorrect. Why not simply `getProductPrice.bind(null, item.productData.ASIN, item.productData.marketPlace)`?

Comment: @SebastianSimon, Thank you for your suggestions. I have changed the code and it now works as expected. I just had to call the pass the `getProductPrice()` function as an argument like, `getProductPrice.bind(null, item.productData.ASIN, item.productData.marketPlace)` and that did the trick.
Totally ignored the fact that i was calling the function when passed as an argument. My bad.

Comment: Thank you @Shuffle for pointing out the mistake. That was a stupid mistake from my side.